# Sprite image appears stretched and quality is poor, can't get in correct position GDXLib

Tags: java, android, image, textures, sprite

I am quite new to programming so bear with me here...

I am making a 2d basic game just to practice programming in android studio and can't get my sprite to the correct position on the screen. Also when I draw the sprite it appears stretched and the quality is very poor. Any help is appreciated!

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture background;
    Texture ball;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        background = new Texture("gamebackground.png");
        ball = new Texture("ball2.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background, 0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.draw(ball, 0,0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
        batch.end();
    }
```

Comment: Which sprite is stretched? `background`or `ball` ? can you attach a screenshot? And how big are the actual textures?

Comment: ball is stretched, background is fine. The texture is 136 x 96 pixels, the background is the whole screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the original width/height ratio:

instead of scaling it to half the screen size, define your scaling like that:

```
float scaleFactor = 2.0f;
batch.draw(ball, 0,0, ball.getWidth()*scaleFactor, ball.getHeight*scaleFactor);
```

If your image is "blurry", and you want the individual pixels to stay crisp, try loading the texture like that:

```
ball = new Texture("ball2.png");
ball.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
```

This prevents (default) linear interpolation when scaling the texture.

Comment: It's looking much better now. Thanks so much for your help man!